# Python: spaces in expressions inside slice/bracket notation

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [style, formatting the slice operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092513/style-formatting-the-slice-operator)

Looked trough [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and not find anything about spaces in expressions inside bracket/slice notation.
For example:

```
my_list[i+n]
```

or

```
my_list[i + n]
```

```
my_list[i:i+n]
```

or

```
my_list[i:i + n]
```

What your preferences in this, without doubt, important aspect of coding?

Comment: They touch on it here: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations

Comment: run `autopep8 yourfile.py` to get pep8-formatted file back or `pep8` just to see pep8 violations.

Comment: This [has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092513/style-formatting-the-slice-operator) and [is quite open to debate](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/space-around-operators-a-b-2-or-a-b-2-what-are-the-arguments)...